# Deployed .war file on Tomcat 7 shows 404 when accessing link

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, centos, tomcat7

To keep it short and cut to the chase, i used to use google's computing cloud to deploy my .war file all fine, but now i want to deploy it locally on a CentOS VM. Trying to deploy the same war file (I packaged them separately, using the same files) throws http '404'.. Here's what i've done so far: (BTW, my .war file is called Mavis)

1) Checked tomcat application manager, has my .war file "/Mavis" available, with "running" set to true.. 0 sessions connected, tried restarting it from the admin dashboard, the "message" section on top doesn't throw an error or anything... clicking on the "/Mavis" link on the dashboard sends me to a 404 page

2) opened up the catalin file... here's the output from the second i deployed the .war till now

> Feb 27, 2018 8:51:14 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
>   INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/Mavis.war
>   Feb 27, 2018 8:51:15 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
>   INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

Doesn't seem like anything serious, could it be that missing jars is what's causing the 404??

And I tried to access my .war through `localhost:8080/Mavis` which doesn't work... however when I had it running on Google computing cloud, the route was `localhost:8080/Mavis/ng/#/` due to some angular needing some routing.. tried that path as well to no avail... anything would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: the info are just messages. The real problem is that it cannot find your context root, probably you did not specify the context root. 404 is just error code for page not found. check your web.xml